# Abelian Group Structures

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism, direct-product

How can I determine all the subgroups of a commutative group, write the Hasse diagram, using Frobenius-Stickelberger Theorem and the isomorphism to $\mathbb{Z}_m$ of a cyclic group? In particular, for example, if $|G|=n$, and $n=pq$ with $p$ and $q$ prime, how can I decide if $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$ or to $\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_q$ (I mean without trying to think and build an isomorphism, but using some theorem or anything else) ?

Comment: Your question is probably going to get marked as "too vague". Also, btw, if $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes then $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}\cong\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_q$.

Answer (score 1):

the best way to do this is to think that the first factor in the
decomposition of $G$ under cyclic groups is of maximum order, more
precisely its order is the exponent of $G$, to joust at Cauchy
result who assure that for all prime $p$ dividing the order of
$G$, it also divides the exponent of this group. As noted in the
comments, if $p$ and $q$ are distinct then it is cyclic group of
order $pq$ (for abelian group, say it is cyclic is equivalent to
his order equal to his exponent) so isomorphic to
$\Bbb{Z}/pq\Bbb{Z}$, particularly
$\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z}/q\Bbb{Z}$ isomorphic to
$\Bbb{Z}/pq\Bbb{Z}$; in the case of $p = q$ are two possibility
for the structure of G, depending in the exponent of $G$  is $p$
or $ p^2$ and $G$ is respectively isomorphic to
$\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ or $\Bbb{Z}/p^2\Bbb{Z}$